# Post CKEDITOR value to action in Asp.net Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, editor

Im using CKEditor 4 and Im going to post ckeditor html value to Action. but when i click on submit buttom and model post to action the ckeditor value posted null value.

**View :**

```
<form asp-controller="Book" asp-action="AddEditBook" id="addeditbook" data-ajax="true" 
  data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-update="#addeditbook" data-ajax-mode="replace">


<div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="BookName" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input asp-for="BookName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BookName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="BookDescription" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" asp-for="BookDescription" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="BookDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<input type="submit" value="submit"/>

}
```

**Model:**

```
 public class AddEditBookViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Book Name:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Book Name")]
    public string BookName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Book Description:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Book Description")]
    public string BookDescription { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller :**

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddEditBook(AddEditBookViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                using (var db = _iServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
                {
                    Book bookModel = Mapper.Map<AddEditBookViewModel, Book>(model);
                    db.books.Add(bookModel);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return view("index");
        }
}
```

How can i post ckeditor html value to action to save or edit?

Comment: You have given the input a `name="editor1"` but you model does not have a property named `editor1` (remove that attribute)

Comment: @StephenMuecke which attribute should i remove?

Comment: `name="editor1"` (and there is no real need for `id="editor1"` to overwrite the existing `id` attribute either - the method already generates `id="BookDescription"` so you could just use `CKEDITOR.replace('BookDescription');`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ohhh thanks. What a bad mistake I committed!!!! it works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forms post back the name/value pairs of its successful form controls and the ModelBinder binds your model based on those values. Your model contains a property named `BookDescription` but you have overwritten the `name` attribute generated by the TagHelper (which is `name="BookDescription"`) and given it `name="editor1"` which is not the name of a property in your model.

Remove the `name="editor1"` attribute so that you input is

```
<textarea id="editor1" asp-for="BookDescription" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

As a side note, the TagHelper also generated `id="BookDescription"` by default, and there is no need to overwrite that attribute either. You could also delete the `id="editor1"` attribute and the script would then be

```
CKEDITOR.replace('BookDescription');
```